# Having problems with my random number guess game

Tags: java, swing, random, while-loop

## I need help with my java code!

Want it to loop threw everything till the user put in the right number. When the user put in wrong number it should say "type in a different number". When the user put in the right number it should say "congrats you won".
But till then it will loop and say "type in a different number" and after 5 tries I want it to say "you failed this mission! do you want to try again?"

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Projekt_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to the guessing game!" + "\nYou     gonna guess a number between 1 and 20." + "\nHOPE YOU LIKE IT!:)");

        Random amount = new Random();
        int guessnumber = anount.nextInt(20);
        int random;

        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 20");
        random = Integer.parseInt(number);

        while (random == guessnumber){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You won!" + "\nYour number was" + "" + guessnumber);      
        }

        if (random < guessnumber){
            number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your number is to high :(" + "\nType in a new lower number!"); 
            random = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }else if (random > guessnumber){
            number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your number is to low :(" + "\nType in a higher number!"); 
            random = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because your only iterative statement is only displaying "You won!..etc":

```
while (random == guessnumber){    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You won!" + "\nYour number was" + "" + guessnumber);      
}
```

---

Enclose the other codes below your while-loop to include them within the while loop. If you ***indent your codes*** properly, you should be able to spot your own problem. This is what you are looking for:

```
while (random != guessnumber){
    //prompt for user input
    if (random < guessnumber){
        //Show Message "Your number is too low...
    }
    else if (random > guessnumber){
        //Show Message "Your number is too high..."
    }
    else{    //got the number
        //Show Message "you won!.."
    }
}
```

Comment: Your else block with "you win" will never get hit, and with the code as is it'll just go into a busy loop outputting the same message (since it's never getting new input)

Comment: @Chris I simplified the solution with comments instead of long codings to improve readability.. the prompt for inputs is in my code comments `Show Message "Your number is too low...prompt input"
`. i.e. he will display and prompt at the same time since op is using JOptionpane.

Comment: It's clearer now wrt prompting, but the else block will still never be hit